# How to get XML attribute values in AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Here is my XML:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(
<navigation playerversion="3.0">
<sequence>
    <chapter number="4" >
        <chapter number="3">
            <screen navigation="false"/>
        </chapter>
    </chapter>
</sequence>
<navigation>);
```

How can I get the two chapter numbers in AS3?

Comment: Can you get the correct node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the rest of the data looks like, you might need to traverse (loop) through the data, but if you just want these two numbers, you can do it by

```
trace(xml.sequence.chapter[0].@number);
trace(xml.sequence.chapter[0].chapter[0].@number);
```

could try something like this:

```
var $xml:XML = new XML(
<navigation playerversion="3.0">
<sequence>
    <chapter number="4" >
        <chapter number="3">
            <screen navigation="false"/>
        </chapter>
    </chapter>
    <chapter number="5" >
        <chapter number="6">
            <screen navigation="false"/>
        </chapter>
        <chapter number="7">
            <screen navigation="false"/>
        </chapter>
    </chapter>
</sequence>
</navigation>);


function getChapter($xml:XML){
    for each(var $e:XML in $xml.chapter){
        trace($e.@number);
        getChapter($e);
    }
}


getChapter(XML($xml.sequence));
```

this will re-curse through each chapter node

and return 4,3,5,6,7

Comment: How can I get these values using loop?

Comment: you can use `xml.sequence.length()` to get number of nodes